# How I can flatten many to many relationship using Django serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am new to Django. While I am try to implement serializer for many to many relationship I got problem.I want to serialize a many to many field and need to create a dictionary based on the nested object.

models.py

```
class ClassRoom(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Teacher(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Student(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
class_room = models.ForeignKey(ClassRoom, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
teacher = models.ManyToManyField(Teacher)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

serializers.py

```
class ClassRoomSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

class Meta:
    model = ClassRoom
    fields = '__all__'

class TeacherSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
teacher_name = serializers.CharField(source="name", label="Teacher")

class Meta:
    model = Teacher
    fields = ['name']

class StudentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
class_room = serializers.CharField(source="class_room.name")
teacher = TeacherSerializer(many=True)
student_name = serializers.CharField(source='name', label="Student")

class Meta:
    model = Student
    fields = ['student_name', 'teacher', 'class_room']
```

views.py

```
class HomeclassView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Student.objects.all()
serializer_class = StudentSerializer
```

> I got the response like this:

```
{
results: [
{
"class_room": "Class 1",
"teacher": [
  {
    "teacher_name": "Maria"
  },
  {
    "teacher_name": "sara"
  }
],
"student_name": "John"
}
]
}
```

> But I am expecting the result in :

```
{
results: [
  {
    "class_room": "Class 1",
    "teacher_name": "Maria",
    "student_name": "John"
  },
  {
    "class_room": "Class 1",
    "teacher_name": "sara",
    "student_name": "John"
  },
  ]
  }
```

Please help me to achieve this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should for on teachers in ModelViewSet:

```
class HomeclassView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = Student.objects.all()
   serializer_class = StudentSerializer

   def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       response = super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
       flat_response = []
       for teacher in response['teacher']:
           res = response.copy()
           del res['teacher']
           res['teacher_name'] = teacher['teacher_name']
           flat_response.append(res)
       return Response(data=flat_response)
```